# How can I have multiple database instances for component tests

Tags: c#

Currently I have a common database used for component tests in xunit, the problem is that when a build is running on teamcity other builds cannot start as while one build is being run a number of tests are being executed which take quite some time. I need some help of how can I have my current class modified/changed in order to have multiple builds executing in parallel using multiple database instances.

```
public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
    {
        public TestCluster Cluster { get; }
        public IGrainFactory GrainFactory => Cluster?.GrainFactory;
        public IClusterClient Client => Cluster?.Client;

        private const string _databaseConnection = @"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true";

            public DatabaseFixture()
        {
            // Find a valid folder for now
            foreach (var folder in _dbFolders)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                    continue;
                _databaseRootFolder = folder;
                break;
            }
            Assert.NotNull(_databaseRootFolder);

            // Create the test database
            CreateDatabase();
            CreateConfigDatabase();

            // Setup and start the cluster
            var builder = new TestClusterBuilder(2);
            builder.AddSiloBuilderConfigurator<DbTestSiloBuilderConfigurator>();

            var testCluster = builder.Build();
            if (testCluster?.Primary == null)
            {
                testCluster?.Deploy();
            }
            Cluster = testCluster;
        }
        
        // other methods that follow have been removed for keeping question short
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but in during build you should only run unit tests. And unit tests shouldn't need database connection.

This means one of two things:

1. What you're testing is an integration test, which should be ran on a test environment, not on build agent.
2. You have bad design of the fixture under test and should refactor it.

Comment: Yes correct integration tests .On a commit/push scenario a build is triggered where tests are executed to ensure that nothing has been broken.

Comment: So you should configure it to be run on a test environment. You will have to configure an environment for it, deploy it there (with database) and run it. I don't use teamcity, but I assume it has similar pattern to what I use in TFS. So you'll have a GC build to run unit tests, than a CI build to create artifacts for your application and then some release build to deploy it to an environment and initiate your tests. This is more less a standard way of doing things.